# Adding a JSON array to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, http-post

I have a AngularJS Function that sends an array to my PHP. But how do I go through this array in PHP and insert each value into MySQL database. SoI have the following $http post:

```
var data = {
  "username": $scope.un,
  "courses": $scope.selectedCourses
}

$http({
url: "submitCourses.php",
method: "POST",
 data: data
 }).success(function(response) {
   $scope.courseSubmitResponse = response.resp;

 });
```

And the $scope.selectedCourses looks like ["COEN 10", "MATH 54", "HIST 99"] when sent over. So how could I insert each of these values into my database? Is there a way I can assign a php variable to the array, then do a for loop of that php variable? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
  "username": $scope.un,
  "courses": $scope.selectedCourses
}

$http({
url: "submitCourses.php",
method: "POST",
 data: data
 }).success(function(response) {
   $scope.courseSubmitResponse = response[0].resp;

 });
```

Try this code only if response array length is one and if you got multiple records in response you need to get value dynamically might for loop is been usefull

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming data transmitted from client side to server side is json.

below is the snippet:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data as $element) {
    list($subject, $mark) = explode(" ", $element);
    // insert using PDO into the database.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Access your data using:

```
$data         = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$user         = $data->username;
$coursesArray = $data->courses;
```

Then loop over your courses and do what you need